# How to properly use standalone TransactionManager in web application?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, jta, atomikos

I'd like to write my next tiny Java webapp by using one of micro-frameworks. E.g. [Spark](http://sparkjava.com/) or [Jooby](http://jooby.org/). The problem is that both of them doesn't support JTA, so I need to use one of third-party libraries. I've googled for open-source JTA implementations and found two: [Atomikos](https://www.atomikos.com/) and [Bitronix](https://github.com/bitronix/btm). It seems that the latter project is slightly abandoned so I've decided to go with Atomikos. Unfortunately documentation is scarce so I can't find answers to my questions.

Here is the use case. Suppose we have two DAO classes which methods should be executed under single transaction:

```
class SomeService {

    // both injected by Guice
    private FooDao fooDao;
    private BarDao barDao;

    public void someMethod() {
        // both methods should be executed in a single transaction
        fooDao.insert(new Foo());
        barDao.insert(new Bar());
    }
}
```

I've never used `javax.transaction` API directly/manually before (you know declarative transactions are very simple with Spring) so I'm a bit confused. JTA provides two general abstractions(`UserTransaction` and `TransactionManager`) and they both have methods to handle JDBC transaction. As far as I understand TransactionManager operates UserTransaction objects by using ThreadLocal variables. Therefore UserTransaction should be thread-confined and TransactionManager supposed to be thread-safe. Am I correct?

So there are several approaches possible:

1. I can inject TransactionManager into my service (via Guice) and use it directly.
2. I can share TransactionManager via public static variable.
3. I can create an UserTransaction provider/factory (via Guice) and get objects from it.

Which is correct/best-practice?

Another question if someone familiar with Atomikos is that it provides two transaction manager implementations (maybe even more): [J2eeTransactionManager](https://www.atomikos.com/downloads/transactions-essentials/com/atomikos/AtomikosTransactionsEssentials/javadoc/3.7/com/atomikos/icatch/jta/J2eeTransactionManager.html) and [UserTransactionManager](https://www.atomikos.com/downloads/transactions-essentials/com/atomikos/AtomikosTransactionsEssentials/javadoc/3.7/com/atomikos/icatch/jta/UserTransactionManager.html). Again documentation is too scarce so I don't see any difference except JNDI. I suppose UserTransactionManager should be enough for my purposes but description states the following

> J2eeTransactionManager
>
> An implementation of TransactionManager that should be used by J2EE
>   applications.

.. without any explanation.

ps. Sorry my english isn't well I know it.

Comment: What kind of transaction-resources do you plan to use? Simple SQL-Databases JMS-Queues/Topics? Is JPA involved, what ORM hibernate or eclipselink? Do you plan to use distributed transactions? Do you want to be able to annotate classes or methods with transaction attributes or are "bean-managed" transactions sufficient?

Comment: @aschoerk All I need is to execute two methods from separate DAO classes in a single transaction. I use simple plain JDBC - no JMS, JPA, XA transactions or any other JEE stuff involved. I do use DI, however. For now I just want to understand how to properly share TM or UserTransaction instance. Declarative transaction management isn't necessary. I suppose, as soon as I'll understand how to utilize TM, it will be simple enough to write custom declarative transactions via reflection proxy.

Comment: Why not share the JDBC-Connection? I think that should be sufficient for you. Just simple "BEGIN TRANSACTION" and "COMMIT TRANSACTION" can be used around your dao-calls, if those use the same connection. That is all, that your TM would do for you under these circumstances.

Comment: @aschoerk Because service layer has no access to JDBC connection. It's the higher level of abstraction which should't know about low-level implementation. Because the result of doing so would be ugly as it spoils DAO API. Because JTA is the thing that was invented for such purposes. I'm grateful for your help but I don't ask for alternative solutions. I just wanna know how to use TM, that's all.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. Technically you are looking for a manager with the interface javax.transaction.* that manages your JDBC-Transactions you use in DAOs so that: they can use the same connection if they are connected by transaction or use distributed transactions (which imO would be an horrible overhead) and encapsulate in transactions as defined in your applicationcode. I think you should look for 3 kinds of objects which must work together: a ConnectionPool, JDBC-Datasource and Transactionmanager since Spark and JOOBS don't come with any support for JDBC and transactions by themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Ок, since no-one answered me, after digging into source code, I think I'm ready to answer my own question:

1. Both Atomikos and Bitronix TMs implemented as singletons [[1]](https://github.com/atomikos/transactions-essentials/blob/master/public/transactions-jta/src/main/java/com/atomikos/icatch/jta/UserTransactionManager.java#L55), [[2]](https://github.com/bitronix/btm/blob/master/btm/src/main/java/bitronix/tm/TransactionManagerServices.java#L66)
2. Both Atomikos and Bitronix TMs are thread-safe. Particularly, Atomikos uses intrinsic synchronization and Bitronix simply doesn't share state between threads.
3. Both [Atomikos](https://github.com/atomikos/transactions-essentials/blob/master/public/transactions-jta/src/main/java/com/atomikos/icatch/jta/UserTransactionManager.java) and [Bitronix](https://github.com/bitronix/btm/blob/master/btm/src/main/java/bitronix/tm/BitronixTransactionManager.java) TMs implement both (oops) TransactionManager and UserTransaction interfaces so in basically doesn't matter which one you'll use. Even if you look at the Atomikos [UserTransactionImp](https://github.com/atomikos/transactions-essentials/blob/master/public/transactions-jta/src/main/java/com/atomikos/icatch/jta/UserTransactionImp.java#L66) class you'll see that it internally instantiates and uses corresponding TransactionManager implementation.

So it is safe to have one TM-per-webapp instance, which you can share any way you like. Since Atomikos [TM supposed to be instantiated](https://www.atomikos.com/Documentation/GettingStartedWithTransactionsEssentials#Simple_JTA_example) it's better to share it through dependency injection. Bitronix TM can be used through [public static method](https://github.com/bitronix/btm/blob/master/btm/src/main/java/bitronix/tm/TransactionManagerServices.java#L66) as any other singleton.

Additionally you can manage transactions via JNDI. You can find an example in the *Java Persistence with Hibernate* book source code.

Comment: I am just curious, how so these solutions guarantee, that your JDBC-Statements really are executed in the transactioncontextes you define by calling begin and commit? Does your JDBC-Implementation find these TMs as well and register there (ok, that seems to be the Atomic-Solution you mus use the AtomicDatasource)? Do you configure the TMs so that they synchronize the JDBC-Connections?

Comment: @aschoerk Each TM only works with javax.sql.DataSource implementation from the same vendor. For instance Atomikos TM must use eitherAtomikosNonXADataSourceBean or AtomikosXADataSourceBean. Bitronix TM must use PoolingDataSource from Bitronix and so on. When you use Spring you can actually use arbitrary data source implementation by passing it to DataSourceTransactionManager but when you use one of forementioned TMs it's not a deal.

Comment: The way they share connection state is vendor-specific. I didn't dig so deep.  But if you look at the much simpler [TM implementation](https://github.com/odnoklassniki/one-datasource/blob/master/src/one/datasource/DataSourceImpl.java#L261) you'll see that it may work via JNDI.